# Using Firestore document data other than ForEach or List SwiftUI

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Is there a way to getting the data out of a document when reading it back from Firestore. Besides Using "ForEach" or "List"

If we look at typical example:

```
struct User: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var surname: String
}

class userViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var users = [User]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
        db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.users = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> User in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let surname = data["surname"] as? String ?? ""
                return User(name: name, surname: surname)
            }
        }
    }
}


    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = userViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.users) { user in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(user.name).font(.title)
                    Text(user.surname).font(.subheadline)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Users")
            .onAppear() {
                self.viewModel.fetchData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My main issue, is in my SwiftUI View, I do not want to create a List. But I want the data out of *viewModel.users*. Grabbing some information I just passed in to be used in my custom screen.
I'm very new to SwiftUI, So I feel I'm just doing something dumb, but the only way I've been able to get the information out is to iterate over it. But it doesn't leave me with the views I would need.

Comment: If you have an array of data, you're going to have to do some sort of iteration. What are you hoping to use/get rather than a `List` or `ForEach`? I'm a little confused about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I cannot figure out, from the array of data how to get a single item out of it to place where I want. For example, I would like to just say viewModel.users[dataIWantToUse] or viewModel.users.dataIWantToUse. Every time I iterate over it, there's a lot of unwanted consequences. So if I can make it Text(viewModel.users.dataIWantToUse) and as long as the data type is a String. It would just show up as text.

Comment: You can definitely do `viewModel.users[x]` as long as `x` is a valid index. I'm just not sure how you'd determine which one you want.

Comment: I'm trying to take the data in the document and fill in cells on another screen that I don't want to scroll. When I do a ForEach or a List it just repeats the data 10 times because that's how many VStacks are allowed. All I want is the data to fill in cells.

Comment: Okay, so you have an array of `User`s -- and you want to know how to pass just one of them to the subsequent screen? But the first screen would still have a list of all of them, right?

Comment: It's actually a 3 pieces of data (Strings), but yes! My code is slightly different than above, but is copied and pasted and I've just added a few bits of Strings into the Struct and fetchData()

Comment: Okay. Do you know how to make a `NavigationLink`? Do you know how to make a `View` that takes one of your `User` objects as a parameter? Something like `UserView(user: user)`

Comment: I've used NavigationLinks before, but only to take me from one View to the next, Can I pass data that lives viewModel.users to be used in the next view?

Comment: Might be a good opportunity to go through the Apple or Hacking with Swift tutorials and get some of the basics down. Do you need me to write an answer that shows passing the user through a NavigationLink?

Comment: It would be super helpful if its specific to using Firestore? Or anything that could be tricky while trying to pass just certain data from the Struct?

Comment: Added an answer. Nothing specific to Firestore -- just passing the `User` as a parameter to the next `View`. Unrelated, but generally, in Swift, you capitalize type names. So, `userViewModel` would be `UserViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, you can send parameters to your new `View` via the `NavigationLink`. Here's a simple example:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = userViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.users) { user in
                NavigationLink(destination: UserView(user: user)) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(user.name).font(.title)
                        Text(user.surname).font(.subheadline)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Users")
            .onAppear() {
                self.viewModel.fetchData()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct UserView : View {
    var user : User
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(user.name)
            Text(user.surname)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?